# how to get the number of the value in a object in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a question about hot to get the number of a value in object with typescript.
the object looks like this:

```
obj : TestObject = {
 name: "test",
 street: "test"
 subobj1: {
   status: warning,
   time: 11
   }
subobj2: {
   status: oki,
   time: 12
   }
subobj3: {
   status: warning,
   time: 13
   }
}


}
```

the TestObject is defined:

```
export interface TestObject {

 name: string,
 street: string,
 subobj1: SubObj1,
 subobj2: SubObj2

}
```

so I want to get the number of warning

I want to a method, which in this case returns 2 back.

how should the code look like?

Comment: Do you want to collect all the values from all the arrays?

Answer (score 3):

First convert the object to array of key and values using `Object.entries` then use `filter` for the condition, finally length of the values is the desired output!

```js
let obj = {
  name: "test",
  street: "test",
  subobj1: {
    status: 'warning',
    time: 11
  },
  subobj2: {
    status: 'oki',
    time: 12
  },
  subobj3: {
    status: 'warning',
    time: 13
  },
}
console.log(Object.entries(obj).filter(([key, value]) => key.indexOf('subobj') > -1 ? value.status === 'warning' : false).length);
```

Comment: Hi, I have edited this object? I have tested your code, it does not work.

Comment: @user1938143 Could you share the object you are testing with, in the question? with this code?

Comment: Hi the error is: Property 'status' does not exist on type TestObject

Comment: @user1938143 Could you share the original angular code where the error occours, if possible a stackblitz. else you can put any type to the property and solve the issue!

Comment: the problem is, the object ist a type of TestObject.

Comment: I have edited my qeustion again.

Comment: @user1938143 updated my answer! could you try now?

Comment: because the satus ist not a element of object, status is in object object.

Comment: @user1938143 Yes for that, I am discarding the elements that do not have status as a property  in my new updated answer, could you check that?

Answer (score 0):

```
let sum = 0;
for (const subobj in obj){
    sum += obj[subobj].status == "warning" ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a `forEach` function on the array generated by the Javascript [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) method.

```
let sum = 0;
Object.values(obj).forEach(value => {
    if(value.status == 'warning'){
        sum += 1;
    }
});
```